# Circular reference in Kotlin Enum

Tags: enums, kotlin, circular-reference

How can I create an enum class with circular references?

Simple example (taken from [this Java question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242471/java-enums-logical-circular-reference)):

```
enum class Hand(val beats: Hand) {
    ROCK(SCISSORS), // Enum entry 'SCISSORS' is uninitialized here
    PAPER(ROCK),
    SCISSORS(PAPER);
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As reassignment is forbidden for `val` properties, this problem is generally hard to solve and often indicates problems in your data model. For a discussion in broader context refer to [this question/answer(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439421/circular-references-with-vals-in-kotlin).

However, this simple example can be solved using a `val` [property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html) with custom getter (thus without a backing field). Using [`when`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression), the getter can be defined in a very readable way:

```
enum class Hand {
    ROCK,
    PAPER,
    SCISSORS;

    val beats: Hand
        get() = when (this) {
            ROCK -> SCISSORS
            PAPER -> ROCK
            SCISSORS -> PAPER
        }
}
```

An alternative solution (analogue to the [answer by Eugen Pechanec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48909881/6525140)) is to use [sealed classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html). Due to their less constrained concept, the implementation is<sup>1</sup> slightly simpler and more readable compared to an `enum` with overridden properties.

```
sealed class Hand {
    abstract val beats: Hand

    object ROCK: Hand() {
        override val beats = SCISSORS
    }

    object PAPER: Hand() {
        override val beats = ROCK
    }

    object SCISSORS: Hand() {
        override val beats = PAPER
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>personal opinion

Disclaimer: I have no information on how these solutions work in conjunction with classic Java.

Comment: Hmm, it's more readable because you use a property with a backing field, which will take up a small amount of memory. I could do that too and have implicit `: Hand()` ^^ Other than that these two cases compile down to virtually the same bytecode.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative to mhoff's answer without flow control statements:

```
enum class Hand {
    ROCK {
        override val beats: Hand
            get() = SCISSORS
    },
    PAPER {
        override val beats: Hand
            get() = ROCK
    },
    SCISSORS {
        override val beats: Hand
            get() = PAPER
    };

    abstract val beats: Hand
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! I wonder if there is a (significant) difference in performance between the two solutions.

Comment: I can say that this will definitely take up more space in memory and on disk. It generates a singleton class (extends Hand) for each of ROCK, PAPER, and SCISSORS. On the other hand this should perform faster - you don't do the switch.

Comment: I have the same problem and I used this solution help me a lot.